# how to produce connected table-like diagram in R

Tags: r, diagram

I would like to produce a diagram like that below in R

[image]

What would be the best way to do it? I have tried DiagrammeR but without success.

Any help would be very appreciated!!!

**EDIT**

Using code by Seshadri I got what I wanted:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be your starting point. Can be improved further.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
items <- paste0('item',c(1:6))
df <- cbind.data.frame(items = c(sample(items,6),sample(items,6),sample(items,6)), x = rep((1:3),each = 6), y = rep(1:6, 3))

ggplot(df,aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = items), size = 1) + 
  geom_tile(width = 0.6, height = 0.6, fill = 'white', color = 'black') + 
  theme_void() + geom_text(aes(label = items))
```

which produces:

[image]